# How to move <dialog> Element with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, dialog

I am working with a simple `<dialog>` element. And I need a opportunity to move my dialog window and to change its size with mouse, when it's show, because now it only has a static fixed-size position in the window. Is it possible and easily achieved with pure JS?

HTML:

```
<dialog id="myDialog">
    This is a dialog window
</dialog>
```

JS:

```
function showMe() {
    document.getElementById("myDialog").show(); 
}
```

Comment: Did you tried anything else apart from showing the dialog?  Also, do you use jQuery?

Comment: I see no more methods of such an object:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_dialog.asp

And I need to avoid jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DIALOG tag doesn't have this capabilities currently.

I think you better use [jQuery's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to reach this functionality.

Or check this [non-jQuery draggable example](http://thezillion.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/javascript-draggable-2-no-jquery/) in case you can't use jQuery.

Comment: I am not allowed to use JQuery or other libs.

Comment: http://thezillion.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/javascript-draggable-2-no-jquery/ is an example of draggable element without jQuery.

Comment: Form as an answer please. It will be checked as a solution.